# Tub drain re-assembly

Tags: bathtub, plumbing-fixture

There was moldy caulk around the tub drain. I intended to take it out, clean the drain area, reapply any teflon tape, and re-caulk the area. When I started to turn the drain counterclockwise the top piece popped off.

[image]
[image]

It appears to be a drain cover. Here's the drain underneath.

[image]

We've cleaned the cover and the top of the drain... now I'm trying to figure out how to put this back on. I was going to apply some plumber's putty to the underside of the cover and stick it on... does that sound like enough adhesion? Should I re-add caulk around the cover once it's back down? Since the cover sits up higher than the drain below there's water that pools around the cover (hence the moldy caulk I was removing) so I'm leaning towards not adding more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to loosen/remove the piece still in there. 
it should just unscrew. The cover you removed doesn't appear to be part of the original drain. If you can remove the remaining piece, you can get a whole new piece to screw back in and no water will be pooling around.

Comment: @bsm  You can purchase a  tub drain wrench to loosen that piece and then reinstall the new piece. Caulk should not be used,plumbers putty is the proper sealant for that application.  I don’t know what that first piece is you took out possibly part of a   Drain plug assembly that was retrofitted it in.

Comment: @Alaska Man  Good point about the wrench and plumbers putty.